# Why does SSMS not install - Error 0x80070643

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016

When trying to install Sql Server Management Studio 18.10 I get the following errors.

"Error 0x80070643" and "Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server: could not get value for key Components\915153DFECF8E204887CDC8C8EEF58D3. Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel."

I already found that installing ODBC driver 17 for SQL Server might help. But when I try this I get the same error. What am I missing? Who can help me out?

Comment: Try running the installer as the (local) administrator.

Comment: Same result. The error persists.